# requests.get(url) can not get html's body

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website.

```
import requests

url='https://stackoverflow.com'

r=requests.get(url)
content = r.text
print(content)
```

For this code ,it works well.But when I try connect other url

```
url='http://www.iyingdi.com/web/article'

#Sorry you guys ,it is a Chinese website.But it does not matter.
#I don't find same problem in others English website.
```

output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--head part works well-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--body part is empty-->
  </body>
</html>
```

head part works well ,but body part is empty!

Try to search in Google or SOF,I have not find same problem.

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: It's because the Chinese url you mentioned, it's content are all dynamicly loaded by javascripts.

Comment: given the dynamic nature of the website you are trying to scrape, Your best bet would be Selenium, with phantomJS driver for instance.
Example at :https://coderwall.com/p/vivfza/fetch-dynamic-web-pages-with-selenium